# Side-by-side configuration is incorrect for Avast antivirus

Tags: windows, anti-virus, avast

I've tried everything from multiple forums online and nothing seems to work.

The error I get says:

```
C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe
The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

So I ran the sxstrace.exe tool and this is what the I got from the .txt file:

```
Begin Activation Context Generation.
Input Parameter:

        Flags = 0
        ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32
        CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
        ManifestPath = C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe
        AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\
        Application Config File =


INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe.

        INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).
        INFO: Reference: Avast.VC110.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="2036b14a11e83e4a",type="win32",version="11.0.60610.1"
INFO: Resolving reference Avast.VC110.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="2036b14a11e83e4a",type="win32",version="11.0.60610.1".

        INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Avast.VC110.CRT\11.0.60610.1__2036b14a11e83e4a\Avast.VC110.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
    INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.
        INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.
            INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.11.0.avast.vc110.crt_2036b14a11e83e4a_11.0.60610.1_none_b2556b4035446b41.manifest
            INFO: Begin assembly probing.
            INFO: End assembly probing.
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
End Activation Context Generation.
```

Anyone knows what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Open your Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features console and check if Avast is in the list of the installed applications. If not, then you need to re-install Avast. If it's listed there, then you need to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 (VC110 is a code for C++ Visual Studio 2012).
You can get it from here: [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Make sure you install x86 and x64 versions side by side - note, you only can install x64 on a 64-bit Windows OS, so if it fails to install x64, then just skip that (no harm done).